# Responsive Best seller

Tags: magento-1.9, php, phtml, best-seller

I have added best seller on my homepage 
referring to this link https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-display-bestselling-products-in-magento-source-code/
but it is not responsive, I want to make it responsive so that products in best seller block doesn't hide with the horizontal scroll bar(at the bottom)[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about css

Comment: css comes under magento

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? There is no question mark in this question. Please edit your question, give a context and explain what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer by just adding following code in my css file

```
float:left
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use responsive carousel

```
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#demo


<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();?>
<?php if ($_productCollection>count()): ?>
    <div class="owl-carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="owl-carousel" id="home-product-slider">
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var owl = jQuery("#home-product-slider");
            owl.owlCarousel({
                responsiveClass: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried using this but I am not understanding how to add this to my products.

Comment: edited my answer with script

Comment: please guide me where i shud put this code

Comment: You will just need to find your bestseller phtml template file and replace that code with this new one.

Comment: If i replace my phtml code with the above code then the best seller is not at all displaying on my home page

Comment: You will need to keep your collection. <?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();?> instead of this you will need to put your collection function. or do one thing add your bestseller code in question so I can check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29843/discussion-between-akhilesh-patel-and-swetha).